# Any suggestion why my regex does not work?

Tags: java, regex

I got the following string to extract some information from:

```
String: String: String Number;
```

Right now I'm using the following regex to get the arguments:

```
(.*?):(.*?):(.*?);$
```

This way I would get with a Matcher the following output:

```
group(1) = String
group(2) = String
group(3) = String Number
```

If I want the number I need to execute another regex on the output of the 3rd group like the following:

```
([a-zA-Z]* ?([0-9])?$)
```

Used ont the String `String Number` this would give me and output like

```
group(1) = String
group(2) = Number
```

I thought about combining both steps and use a regex like `(.*?):(.*?):([a-zA-Z]* ?([0-9])?);$` on the `String: String: String Number;`-String. But this does not work and I dont see the reason.

Comment: Why is you third bracket around the String and the Number? Should it not be just the String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hwere you go, I added some extra whitespace matching, but this seems to work, you were missing the whitespace between the second : and the following string

```
 ^(.*?):\s*(.*?):\s*([a-zA-Z]*\s+([0-9])?);$
```

Comment: Alright :) Thank you for this. I changed a little bit to fit my code. `^(.*?):\\s*(.*?):\\s*([a-zA-Z]*)\\s+([0-9])?;$` So It gives me the string in group(3) and the number in group(4).